# An error is returned when loading an extension in sqlite3

Tags: database, sqlite, go

```
db, err := sql.Open("sqlite3", "./map.gpkg")
if err != nil {
    panic(err.Error())
}
defer db.Close()

_, err = db.Exec("SELECT load_extension('mod_spatialite');")

if err != nil {
    panic(err.Error())
}
```

In the code above, SELECT load_extension('mod_spatialite'); When executing the line, the following error is returned:

```
panic: not authorized
```

I don't know why this error occurs, it seems that the extension is not loaded properly

Also, what files do I need to download to use the mod_spatialite extension? Or is it possible to simply use the extension by loading it?

please help

Comment: I think you are misusing `sql.Open`.  This opens a connection to a database, the second argument being the database information (address, port, user, password, etc). This is not opening any file.

Comment: if you open command line client `sqlite3 ./map.gpkg` and try `.load mod_spatialite`? Does it give the same error?

Comment: panic: no such column: “mod_spatialite”

an error occurs

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70837250/is-it-possible-to-get-multipolygon-type-data-as-string-from-spatialite same content