# Is it possible to get multipolygon type data as string from spatialite?

Tags: sqlite, go, geometry, spatialite

```
sql.Register("sqlite3_with_extensions",
    &sqlite3.SQLiteDriver{
        Extensions: []string{
            "mod_spatialite",
        },
    })

db, err := sql.Open("sqlite3_with_extensions", "./map.gpkg")
if err != nil {
    panic(err.Error())
}

query := "select AsText(geom) from level0"
rows, err := db.Query(query)
if err != nil {
    panic(err.Error())
}

for rows.Next() {
    var s []byte
    rows.Scan(&s)
    fmt.Print(s)
}
```

First of all, the code I wrote is as above, I want to receive the geom data as text like multipolygon((((......))) , but only an empty array is returned.

Below is what the database looks like, data is stored in multipolygon type
[image]

Loading this data into golang returns data like the picture below[image]

I want text like multipolygon ((((......))) , not datatype like above, but I don't know how to do it,

I have loaded extended spatialite into sqlite3 and loaded data through astext, but an empty array is returned as [], [], [] . How can I return the multipolygon text I want? Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "log"

    "github.com/twpayne/go-geom/encoding/wkb"
    "github.com/twpayne/go-geom/encoding/wkt"


    _ "github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3"
)

func main() {
    db, err := sql.Open("sqlite3", "./gadm36_levels.gpkg")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    rows, err := db.Query("select geom from level0 limit 1")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    defer rows.Close()

    for rows.Next() {
        var b []byte
        var mp wkb.MultiPolygon

        if err := rows.Scan(&b); err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }

        if err := mp.Scan(b[40:]); err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }

        log.Printf("%+v", *mp.MultiPolygon)

        text, err := wkt.Marshal(mp.MultiPolygon)
        if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
        }

        log.Printf("%v\n", text)
    }
}
```

40 is offset of WKB block.

Comment: It doesn't work with an error like this
 Scan error for column index 0, name "ST_AsBinary(geom)": Unsupported scan, driver. Store value type <nil> in type *geom.MultiPolygon

Comment: for rows.Next() {
  var s *geom.MultiPolygon
  if err := rows.Scan(&s); err != nil {
   panic(err.Error())
  }
  fmt.Print(s)
 }

Comment: *geom.multipolygon type scan returns nil, please help

Comment: `var mp geom.MultiPolygon` is a value, not a pointer.

Comment: sql: Scan error on column index 0, name "ST_AsBinary(geom)": unsupported Scan, storing driver.Value type <nil> into type *geom.MultiPolygon

Comment: If you scan with geom.multipolygon type instead of pointer, the above error is returned.

Comment: try without ST_AsBinary()

Comment: It returns data like
{{{{0 0 [] 0}} []}}{{{{0 0 [] 0}} []}}{{{{0 0 [] 0}} []}}{{{0 0 [] 0}} []}}{{{0 0 [] 0}} []}}{{{0 0 [] 0}} []}}

Comment: when try without ST_AsBinary

Comment: is it possible to get ./map.gpkg file? Can you provide a link to it? Without DB sample it is difficult to understand what is going on.

Comment: Thanks, the data is being received

multipolygon(((........)))

Is there no way to receive this in text format?

Comment: multipolygon (((...))) I want to return text in this format, the text as it appears in the database. Is there a way?? sorry

Comment: I want to save it directly to the mysql database, but I can't save it because the format is wrong.

Comment: use `wkt.Marshal` to convert to text format.

Comment: I'm really sorry, but can you show me a simple example?

Comment: I updated the example. Look for wkt.Marshal

Comment: t, err := wkt.Marshal(mp)
  if err != nil {
   panic(err.Error())
  }
  fmt.Print(t)

return error like this geom: unsupported type wkb.MultiPolygon

Comment: `wkt.Marshal(mp.MultiPolygon)`

Comment: Thank you so much, it works perfectly, thanks again